# Do you prefix/postfix classes with directory name?

Tags: php, naming-conventions

I have some Dashboard module.

```
Dashboard
├── Components
├── Policies
├── Queries
└── QueryScopes
    └── UserActivity (this corresponds to component)
```

`Dashboard\DashboardBuilder` vs just `Dashboard\Builder`?

`Dashboard\DashboardComponent` (interface) vs just `Dashboard\Component`?

`Dashboard\Queries\UserActivityQuery` vs just `Dashboard\Queries\UserActivity`?

`Dashboard\Policies\UserActivityPolicy` vs just `Dashboard\Policies\UserActivity`?

What are some pros/cons?
What do you use?

Note:
I have tried to find out what convention is Laravel following but even there are some inconsistencies (`Policies\PostPolicy` but `Query\Builder`).